# LEFT JOIN error with workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

i am trying to get a list of cases with total and passed cases. Here is the query i wrote-

```
select totalcases.feature,passedcases.passed,totalcases.total 

from ((select feature, count(distinct templateid) as Total 
       from results 
       where build = 'random' group by feature
       ) AS totalcases) 
LEFT JOIN ((select feature,count(distinct templateid) as PASSED 
            from results 
            where build='random' and result='PASS' group by feature
       ) AS passedcases) using feature;
```

mysql says there's some syntax error . Also, does workbench not allow a query to be broken in different lines like the terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do much simpler using group by

```
select  feature,
            sum(case when result = 'PASS' then  1 else 0 end) as passed,
            count(*) as totalcases 
from        results
where       build = 'random'
group       by feature
order       by feature
```